# How to change a font size within a plot figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I can't figure out how to change the objects font size on y ticks. Any suggestions?
Here is the screenshot:
[image]

```
 objects = (maternal_mortality['Country Name'])
 y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
 width = .5

 year_1990 = maternal_mortality['1990']
 year_2015 = maternal_mortality['2015']


 plt.barh(y_pos +width, year_1990, align='center', alpha=0.5,  label='1990')
 plt.barh(y_pos +width, year_2015, align='center', alpha=0.5, label='2015')



 plt.yticks(y_pos, objects)
 plt.xlabel('Percentage')
 plt.title('Maternal Death Worldwide in 1990 vs 2015')

 plt.legend()
 plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))

 plt.show()
```

Comment: it didn't work @vatsal mevada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `tick_params` function like `plt.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', labelsize=10)`